# #176-D expression has no effect" warning when I created an array of function pointers. What is going on here?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, command-line-interface, uart

I am having trouble understanding what is going on. I am working on a command line interface for a small robot using a Texas Instruments micro controller and one of my professors recommended an array of function pointers, so I did just that. My code compiles, but I am receiving a warning:

```
#176-D expression has no effect uartconsole.c
```

Here is my function my function:

```
void startConsole(void)
{

    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);

    Configure_UART1();

        // Enables port, sets pins 1-3 (RGB) pins for output
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);

    unsigned char *input;

    void (*p[4])(unsigned char);


    p[0] = forward;
    p[1] = reverse;
    p[2] = left;
    p[3] = right;



    /* printf goes to the UART com port */
    printf("\f======== Welcome to the Console ========\n");
    printf("Enter a command followed by return.\n"
           "Type help for a list of commands.\n\n");



    /* Loop forever receiving commands */
    while(true) {
        /* Get the user's input */
        if(UARTCharsAvail(UART_BASE)) {
            input = UARTCharGet(UART_BASE);



            switch(*input) {
                case 'fo':
                    (*p[0]);
                case 're':
                    (*p[1]);
                case 'le':
                    (*p[2]);
                case 'ri':
                    (*p[3]);
                default:
                    UARTPutString(UART_BASE, "\nCommand Unknown\n\r");
            }
        }
```

How can I fix this warning ? I have looked up previous Stackoverflow posts regarding function pointers, but I'm not understanding why this is giving my error still.

Comment: In the future, provide a [mcve] and indicate which line the warning message applies to.

Comment: `case 'fo':` (and the other case statements) should be warning about multi-character character constants. Those case statements will not do what you expect.

Comment: `*p[0]`; -> `p[0]()`;

Answer (score 2):

`(*p[0])` designates the function pointed to by `p[0]`. It does not call the function. To call the function, you must apply parentheses and an argument, as with `(*p[0])(*input)`. In the absence of a function call, the statement `(*p[0]);` is merely a function designator that is discarded without performing any action, so the compiler is warning you that is not what you meant to do.